# How to set parameter in IEnumerable in Where part

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, ienumerable

I wan't to know - could i pass specific parameter in Where part of IEnumerable ? 
for example i have query like this :

```
 IEnumerable<Bla> quer  = quer.Where(e => e.actual == 1 && param);
```

Where `param` will be like this

```
 e.Number > 5
```

I think it could be done through `IsNullOrEmpty` but maybe with generics ?
I work with EF , it is Web Forms  .

```
 public class BLA
    {
        [Key]
        public int IDin { get; set; }
        public int actual { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }     
        public DateTime Date  { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: We need to see the type of IEnumerable that you are dealing with

Comment: declare parameter as `Func<paramType,bool> param`

Comment: @OrelEraki It's no matter for me  -  it can be any type. I just wan't to know how can it be done - the idea of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define `param` to be a function (`Func<Bla, bool>` to be precise), you can call it:

```
Func<Bla, bool> param = bla => bla.Number > 5;
```

And calling it:

```
IEnumerable<Bla> quer  = quer.Where(e => e.actual == 1 && (param?.Invoke(e) ?? true));
```

The `?? true` allows you to default the outcome when `param` is `null`. Now it will return `true` if `param` is `null`, but you can change that if you want to.

Since you are running EF, you can't use this the above way.

You can use an `Expression<Func<Bla, bool>>`. An expression can be translated by EF to the actual SQL:

```
Expression<Func<Bla, bool>> param = bla => bla.Number > 5;

IEnumerable<Bla> quer  = quer.Where(e => e.actual == 1)
                             .Where(param);
```

For complexer functions, you have to materialize the outcome first:

```
IEnumerable<Bla> quer  = quer.Where(e => e.actual == 1)
                             .ToList() // materialize
                             .Where(e => param?.Invoke(e) ?? true);
```

Comment: This won't work when the query is running against EF, as stated.

Comment: @PeterB I missed that. Updated.

Comment: if param was an Expression<Func<Bla,bool>>, it could be translated into SQL. Why retrieve more data than necessary and do the round-trip over Function.Invoke() rather than using Expression?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Agreed. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters where condition in any linq always results a boolean value. 
That is e.actual == 1 is boolean result either true or flase. like that it will be a param also need to boolean. var param = e.Number > 5 okay but var param = "e.Number > 5" not okay.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to apply the second condition only when it is needed, like this:

```
// Always apply first condition:
IEnumerable<Bla> query = quer.Where(e => e.actual == 1);

// When needed, also apply second condition:
int? valueToCheck = someValue; // or null
if (valueToCheck.HasValue)
{
    query = quer.Where(e.Number > valueToCheck.Value);
}
```

However if you even need to vary the `e.Number >` part, then this approach will be not so easy to follow.

It can also be written a bit shorter (and perhaps more readable) like this:

```
int? valueToCheck = someValue; // or null
IEnumerable<Bla> query = quer
    .Where(e => e.actual == 1);
    .Where(e => valueToCheck == null || e.Number > valueToCheck.Value);
```

Comment: now my code is like this , but i wan't to make it shorter and more abstract

Comment: I added a shorter notation, maybe you like it better this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameter, and add it to the query

```
Expression<Func<Bla, bool>> param = bla => bla.Number > 5;
IEnumerable<Bla> query = query.Where(e => e.actual == 1).Where(param);
```

Since it is two calls, you can simply omit the second call if it is null.

```
public void SomeMethod(Expression<Func<Bla, bool>> param) {
    IEnumerable<Bla> query = quer.Where(e => e.actual == 1).Where(param);
    if (param != null) {
        query = query.Where(param);
    }
    // ...
}

// Usage
SomeMethod(null);
// or
SomeMethod(bla => bla.Number > 5);
```